# Replacing images on a page with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, replace, google-chrome-extension, background-image, onload

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that will replace some images on https://www.ourgroceries.com/ with my own images.

Specifically, I want to replace the top buttons *"overview-label", "features-label", faq-label", "your-lists-label", "download-label".*

I tried to use this code to replace "overview-label", but it didn't work:

```
window.onload = function () {document.getElementById("overview-label").style.backgroundImage="url('http://www.321space.com/content/space_telescope/thumb_small/opo0317d.jpg')";};
```

I tried using this script locally, and it worked, which means that maybe there's a script on this website that prevents changing these images, but I couldn't find it.

Any ideas how to replace these images?

Comment: Your question does not tell us much about how you execute this script. Please edit your question with more information about your extension (where is that code, your manifest, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an extension like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) or write you own one using [contentscripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.ourgroceries.com/*"],
    "css": ["mystyles.css"]
  }
],
```

Comment: I used stylish [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and it worked great! thank you!